# How to make an interesting story about a cat?

Tags: short-story, story

I never had the experience of writing a proper story, so I am confused about how to start and end the story. Also, please provide some some tips to make the story interesting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Step 1: Ask stackexchange how to write the start and end and some tips to make the story interesting. Step 2: Copy-paste all the instructions and tips you got from stackexchange into a prompt for ChatGPT and let ChatGPT write the story. Step 3: Profit.

Answer (score 2):

1. To write a story, you need an interesting idea. "A story about a cat" is not an interesting idea. Here is a boring story about a cat:

   > There once was a cat. It slept most of the day. When it woke up, it stretched and yawned. Then it licked some water from a creek and went hunting. It caught a mouse and ate it. It then licked its fur clean and went to sleep. The next day, the cat went to hunt again. One day the cat died from old age.

   To make a story interesting, something has to happen that deviates from the common, mundane, unremarkable, everyday life of the average cat.
2. To find something interesting to write about a cat, brainstorm.

   a. Think about your own relation to cats. What role have cats played in your life, what have you experienced with them, what interests you about them? Why do you want to write a story about a cat? What do you find interesting about cats? What interesting events that you know about involve cats? What stories do you know about cats?

   b. Collect all your thoughts and ideas on a piece of paper.

   c. Put that piece of paper and a pencil in your pocket and take a walk. Think about the thoughts and information you have collected. Which of these spark images or small scenes in your mind? Which seem to join or relate to each other in some way? Take notes about the ideas you have.

   d. Back home, order your thoughts. Write out the scenes and the connections between them.

   e. By now you should have one or several ideas about stories that you could write about a cat. (If not, writing is not for you, because apparently you lack the creative mind necessary to come up with interesting ideas.)
3. From the story idea, there are two ways you can write:

   a. Outline the story. Flesh out your idea. Where is the cat at the beginning of the story? What happens to set the events in motion? What goal does the cat want to achieve? Which obstactes does the cat have to overcome? How does it succeed? What is the final outcome? Where is the cat at the end of the story?

   or

   b. Choose an interesting scene and start to write from there. Try and get into the mind of the cat and into the logic of your story and let your intuition guide you from one event to the next until you feel your story has reached its end.
4. Give your story to a few test readers and collect their feedback. Then revise your story.

That's it! That's how you write an interesting story about a cat. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter if your hero is a cat, or a person.

Especially for beginning story tellers, I suggest an 8 part story, each part about equal in length. This can apply to novels or short stories.

**1/8:** The Normal World. This is the normal world of the hero, the cat. We are introduced to the hero, doing their normal routine, perhaps solving a normal everyday problem. But at the end of this 1/8, something odd happens. We call this the "inciting incident". Something different, the hero has not encountered before, something that causes a bit of a problem for the hero.
But really, the inciting incident is just the tip of an iceberg. For a cat, this could be anything like accidentally ending up outside, for an indoor cat. Or a new neighbor cat.

**2/8:** The Escalation. As the hero deals with the inciting incident, instead of getting better, it gets worse! In fact, by  the end of this 2/8, it gets so bad that the hero can no longer continue their old routine, they must abandon their "Normal World" to deal with this big problem they have.

**3/8:** The Strange New World. The hero has left their Normal World, and now they face a strange new world. New rules, new characters. And they do not do well! They make mistakes. They get hurt. Or frightened. Maybe your cat gets hungry, and is going to spend the night outdoors for the first time in their life. Maybe the cat gets in fight and beat up.

**4/8:** You Thought That Was Bad? Now the hero, still trying to solve the original problem, knows a little bit about the Strange New World. But not enough. Trying to avoid the dangers found so far, the hero comes up with a new idea. The end of 4/8 is a turning point, the hero finally has a plan!

**5/8:** But it fails. Miserably. It fails so bad, the hero feels defeated, rejected. Maybe they have lost a friend, or been injured. They are hurt, they despair, they don't know what to do. But here, this what makes a fiction hero heroic: **They would rather die than fail.** By the end of 5/8, your hero should be determined to risk *everything* on one -- last -- shot. Think of Luke Skywalker, risking his life against the Death Star, with one last shot to destroy it. And the only way to make that impossible shot -- Trust the Force, Luke! That is what happens in 5/8, your hero gets one last idea, a nearly impossible leap to make.

**6/8:** Get up. Get out. Get ready! The hero pulls themselves together. Get Ready for the Mission.

**7/8:** The mission! We do it, and barely, just barely succeed! The problem is solved, at last!

**8/8:** The New World. Your hero can return to their old world, or if that no longer exists, with the big problem solved, the hero enters a "New Normal". Now they understand the bigger world, and how it works, and how to navigate it. But warriors come home, or find peace. A new Normal. For example, Luke Skywalker cannot go home, but he has fully become a Jedi, and has a new place in society. Bruce Willis (in Die Hard) has killed the bad guys and rescued his wife and daughter, he can go back to his normal.

For your cat: Maybe the cat finds their original home, or finds a new home if that is impossible.

Good luck!